# Extracting an array from an image

Tags: image-processing

Consider the following array:

```
array = Partition[Mod[Range[96^2], 250], 96];
```

We can make an image out of this.

```
image = Image[NumericArray[array]]
```

[image]

How can I get the array back out from "image"?  What piece of code can I apply to "image" to get that array back?

Answer (score 4):

```
ImageData[image, "Byte"] == array
```

> True